# Evaluating $\lim_{\alpha\to 1}\frac{x_0^{1-\alpha}x^{\alpha}-x}{1-\alpha}$

Tags: calculus

I have an engineering equation:

$$y=\frac{x_0^{1-\alpha}x^{\alpha}-x}{1-\alpha}$$

where $x_0$ is a constant and $\alpha$ is a parameter.

A potential singularity arises for $\alpha =1$ because then:

$$y=\frac{x-x}{1-1}=\frac{0}{0}$$

Can anyone show me how to determine:

$$\lim_{\alpha \to 1}y$$

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried hospitalizing $y$?

Comment: @Klangen: my knowledge of limit theory is scant. I could stretch to a numerical determination but that's about it!

Comment: While not a proof, it would be interesting to see what happens when you graph this in DESMOS. Keep the $a$ and the $x_0$ variable as a parameter and then while graphing, set $a=1$ and keep $x_0$ variable. What you get is a line with slope $-1$ that moves up-down. This fixed slope appears to be consistent with Doug's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have already shown that you have an indeterminate form

Applying L'Hopital's rule:

The derivative of the numerator $\frac {d}{da} e^{(1-a)\ln x_0+a\ln x} - x = x_0^{1-a}x^a(\ln x-\ln x_0)$

as $a$ approaches $1,$ we get: $x(\ln x - \ln x_0)$

and the derivative of the denominator is $-1$

$x(\ln x_0 - \ln x)$

Comment: Thank you very much. No infinity in sight, which is the main thing.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x=x^ax^{1-a}$

Thus $$\frac{x_0^{1-\alpha}x^{\alpha}-x}{1-\alpha}=\frac{x^{\alpha}(x_0^{1-\alpha}-x^{1-\alpha})}{1-\alpha}=\frac{x^{1-t}(x_0^{t}-x^{t})}{t}=\frac{x^{1-t}((\frac{x_0}{x})^t-1)}{t}$$

where $t=1-a$ and $t \to 0$ as $a \to 1$

> Thus $$\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{x^{1-t}((\frac{x_0}{x})^t-1)}{t}=xf'(0)$$ where $f(t)=(\frac{x_0}{x})^t$

Answer (score 1):

For the limit itself, you already received good and simple answers.

Since this is an engineering problem, you could be interested by the fact that Taylor expansions built at $\alpha=1$ can give you the limit but also how it is approached.
$$y=x \log \left(\frac{x_0}{x}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{x_0}{x}\right)(\alpha -1)+O\left((\alpha -1)^2\right)\right)$$

Answer (score -2):

The notation is quite confusing and I think it is simpler if you write the problem as

$f(x) = \frac{ac^x-b}{1-x}$, where $a=x_0, b=x, c=\frac{x}{x_0}.$

$$\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)$$ now looks elementary(doesn't it?).